# Where the data was put in wpf client app with client/server model with mvvm light?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, client-server, mvvm-light

There is a class which is responsible for communicating with server and hold the most of data.  In client, There is without database.

VMs will get required data from the class instance.

Now I'm doubt where the class instance to be put, in App class? in ViewModelLocator class? or others?

Are there some opensource projects like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on the size of your project. If I write a small MVVM application (with a single project), then I create the following folders:

> Converters (if required)
>
> DataTypes - some developers put this into 'Models' also, but I prefer to separate them
>
> Models - I use this for data access classes <<< put your class in here <<<
>
> Utilities - some developers call this 'Services'
>
> ViewModels
>
> Views

If the application is large, then I create separate projects with these names instead and add a few others as well.